# Eclipse Integrated CVS Plugin Cannot Delete Repositories

Tags: eclipse, plugins, repository, cvs

I'm currently working in Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) and CVS Integration 1.4.300

I'm experiencing some unusual behavior that must be attributed to a bug of some sort in the plugin.  When I attempted to change some properties in my saved SSH repository (User and Host fields), a new repository was created instead of updating the existing one.

When I attempt to delete the old repository from the CVS Repositories list via context menu, nothing happens.  When I attempt to delete the newly created repository, it disappears.  After restarting Eclipse, the deleted repository reappears.

Is anyone aware of this bug?  If not, does anyone know where the CVS plugin pulls this data from so I can attempt to manually delete it?  I found the information appears to be stored in **metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui\repositoriesView.xml**  and **metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui\dialog_settings.xml**, but the repositories in these files repopulate after startup.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you keep projects from that repository in your workspace?

Comment: @nitind Yes, I've kept the projects from that repository in my workspace, however I have disconnected them from the associated Repositories in the Team menu.  Is it possible they are retaining some metadata that is repopulating the CVS view?